# how to disable the date part in datepicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

hai 
i need to show the date picker dialog with month and year alone.
how to disable that part alone.
Or i need to create the custom date picker

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the dialog is not configurable. Neither is the 
underlying DatePicker widget, AFAIK. You may be able to subclass 
DatePicker and have it use a different layout, or clone the DatePicker 
source code to create your own YearAndMonthPicker. Then, you can wrap 
that in an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

you have to custom your own date picker , or another bad  solution is just to resize it manually till the date part is not shown anymore !